# How do I add source to a manually created module?

Tags: python, python-importlib

If I create a module from a source file, I get better errors than if I create it from a string. Can I attach the source to a module created from a string?

```
import sys, importlib
import traceback
my_name = 'mod'
my_spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(my_name, loader=None)
my_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(my_spec)
code = '''
def a():
    return x
'''
def b():
    return x
exec(code, my_module.__dict__)
sys.modules[my_name] = my_module
import mod
try:
    b()
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
try:
    mod.a()
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

You'll note the traceback includes the line of code causing the problem in the source, but not the string:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\numba50\python.exe 
a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 22, in <module>
    b()
  File "a.py", line 15, in b
    return x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 28, in <module>
    mod.a()
  File "<string>", line 3, in a
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Why don't you create the module from a file instead?

Comment: In reality I am doing something transforming an AST. I could print it back somewhere but it seems silly.

Comment: I'd also prefer to have the un-transformed source in the stacktrace if possible.